# Does Angular destroy component's properties after leave?

Tags: angular

According this component code:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-create-plan",
  templateUrl: "./create.html",
  styleUrls: ["../calendar-thematic-plan-create.component.css"]
})
export class CreatePlanComponent extends CalendarThematicPlanCreateComponent
  implements OnDestroy {
  public rows: any[] =[];
  constructor() {}
```

Does  Angular destroy component's properties like `public rows: any[] =[];` after leaving component? Or I must do this himself in ngOnDestroy?

```
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.rows = [];
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends, if the component is really destroyed, all the property are destroyed within it. Be aware, if you are using routing, something like:

```
{path: ':id', component: someRandomComponent }
```

Angular will reuse the component if only the id in the url change, in that case, you have to pay attention to the properties in the component because they are not reinitialized.

Comment: Okay, then why I see data in destructor: ` ngOnDestroy(): void {
    console.log(this.rows);
  }` Can I ensure that this.rows is empty after leaving component?

Comment: ngOnDestroy is called **before** destruction. So if you log any data in there, you will see its actual value (because the component is not actually destroyed yet ...)

Comment: Take a look on ngOnDestroy event hook here for more info : https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks **Cleanup just before Angular destroys the directive/component. Unsubscribe Observables and detach event handlers to avoid memory leaks.

Called just before Angular destroys the directive/component.**